# Build the SBTSDK with maven

Tags: maven, build, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

we're currently working on an automatic process to checkout, build and deploy the SBTSDK to our tomcat.
So i cloned the rep from github and try to build the project with maven from command line.
At the moment im stuck at the following error:

```
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: com.ibm.sbt.prereq:com.ibm.sb
t.libs.j2ee:1.0.0 @ C:\sbtsdk\prereqs\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.sbt.libs.j2
ee\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository http://dubgsa.ibm.com/gsa/dubgsa/home/m/w/mwdu1054/web/
public/repository/p2
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.
ProvisionException: Bad HTTP Request: http://dubgsa.ibm.com/gsa/dubgsa/home/m/w/
mwdu1054/web/public/repository/p2/content.xml: HttpClient connection error respo
nse code 400. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeExcept
ion: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Bad HTTP Request: http://du
bgsa.ibm.com/gsa/dubgsa/home/m/w/mwdu1054/web/public/repository/p2/content.xml
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionExce
ption: Bad HTTP Request: http://dubgsa.ibm.com/gsa/dubgsa/home/m/w/mwdu1054/web/
public/repository/p2/content.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformBuilderImpl.addP2Repository
(TargetPlatformBuilderImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.addEntireP2Rep
ositoryToTargetPlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.computeTargetP
latform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolv
eProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProj
ectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Bad HTTP Request: htt
p://dubgsa.ibm.com/gsa/dubgsa/home/m/w/mwdu1054/web/public/repository/p2/content
.xml
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(C
acheManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.TychoP2RepositoryCacheManager.createCache
(TychoP2RepositoryCacheManager.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRep
ositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRep
ositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepository
Manager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepository
Manager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositor
yManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepos
itory(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformBuilderImpl.addP2Repository
(TargetPlatformBuilderImpl.java:234)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException: HttpClient
connection error response code 400.
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystem
Browser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowse
r$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Since i found the following readme file i wonder if it is even possible to build the project without eclipse.

> The build is still under development, we are working on removing the
>   internal dependancies. Please import the projects into an Eclipse
>   workspace and use Eclipse to build the SDK projects.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: we are building it outside of eclipse. I'll ask a colleague to respond with more insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working at fixing this problem for non domino users. 
The update will be merged the end of this week.

You can check out the working maven build out of my git tree, pure-maven branch:

https://github.com/LorenzoBoccaccia/SocialSDK/tree/pure-maven

This will allow you to test your tomcat integration and should be painless to upgrade to the upstream tree after the merger.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lorenzo. At the moment i'm just working with your commit from Nov, 27 at the github OpenNTF repository with the SHA 04459e7691d21165b1ecd3fa15c90e329d681090. Thats the last commit i could build the sbt war using the included build.cmd. Would be great if this would work in future commits again.

Comment: Have you tried from the main repository? That now is a plain maven build. Public build status is here https://travis-ci.org/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/builds

Comment: The latest stable release/tag from github works perfect. Thanks for your help.